# How do I use nested loops but increase value by 2 every time it loops

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am begginer and was just doint some basic excercies in Python. Basically I need to print following sequence of numbers:

This is what the multiplication table is up to 5 times 5.

↳
1 2 3 4 5

2 4 6 8 10

3 6 9 12 15

4 8 12 16 20

5 10 15 20 25

Write a program that displays a multiplication table up to 20 times 20.

Also so far I have only learned loops and how to nest them so I think I need to solve problem using nested loops.

```
i=1
for loop in range(20):
   for loop in range (20):
      print(i, end = " ")
      i=i+1
   print() 
for loop in range(20):
   print(i, end = " ")
   i=i+2
```

I have tried this but prints sequence of number that continues instead to start from 1 every time. I am sure I need to use loop where my value is incrementing by 2 every time that loops but I'm not sure how. Also please if you can give me short explination on the solution. Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the syntax of the `range` function

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    for j in range(1, 21):
        print(j * i, end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: Thank you! can you take 2 sec to explain me this code please.

Comment: so the first loop is the multiplication factor ( from 1 to 20)  while the second loop represent all your numbers from 1 to 20 (multiplied with the multiplication factor) to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, closer to what you tried to do:

```py
for i in range(1,11): #number of rows you want to print 
    for j in range(i,i*5+1,i): # go from i to i*5 with a step of i
        print(j,end=' ')
    print()
```